# Instantiate scala class with language defaults

Tags: scala

Is there a way to instantiate a Scala class with "language default" values, e.g. zeros for all numerics and null for others? Maybe some library that uses reflection?

Comment: have you thought of [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) ? It is Java and _an overkill_ but... gets you the `0`s and `null`s that you wanted

Comment: but anyways, `null`s are really frowned upon in scala

Comment: @Yaneeve Yes! Great suggestion, just now I thought of using scalamock.

Comment: You know that a `var` will default to `0` or `null`. Not the ideal solution, but ...

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be set the default values in the class definition:

```
class MyClass(val a: Int = 0, b: String = "defaultValue")
```

Also, you could have different constructor methods ('def this(...)') within that class and set the default values in there.

```
class MyClass(val a: Int, b: String) {
  def this(aValue: Int) = {
   this(aValue, "defaultValue")
  }
}

new MyClass(0, "String")
new MyClass(0)
```

The other approach is have a companion object, in which you create an instance passing the values you need, through the apply method.

```
object MyClass {
  def apply() : MyClass = {
    new MyClass(15, "defaultValueFromCO")
  }
}

MyClass()
```

Comment: Imagine we need a universal solution. In your proposal I need to add it to each class manually, which can be tedious.

Comment: Yes, you are right about it. Sorry I didn't get what you were asking exactly!